# Mount a ceiling fan to a metal gazebo

Tags: electrical, outdoor

I'm going to mount a ceiling fan to a metal gazebo.   Should I ground the gazebo frame to the ground wire?  Plan on conduit from the house to a switch in a sealed environmental type electrical box.  Any other electrical considerations I should be aware of?  GFCI?

Comment: grounding is always good

Comment: Have you considered the mechanics of attaching a big, heavy, vibrating thing to your gazebo's frame?

Comment: It's a wet location. GFCI is _always_ good and required by newer versions of code - exceeding code is always fine, too. Protection at the breaker is nice and simple, but somewhat more expensive. Protection from a GFCI outlet (with the switch & fan wired to the LOAD side of the receptacle) installed _inside_ somewhere upstream is perfectly acceptable.